# Can’t get index.max_result_window for Elasticsearch 7 working

Tags: elasticsearch

For some reason I cannot set `index.max_result_window` from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings 1

I have tried different options like

```
PUT /articles/_settings { "max_result_window" : 25000 }
```

and I can see that it was set when I run

```
GET /articles/_settings
```

but still, when I run any search like match_all I get only 10000 results back.

I'm aware about all memory complications associated with it but I have pretty small index less than 25K documents so I would like to enable it

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`max_result_window` will only set the maximum number of hits you can request from a given query, it doesn't change the **default** number of hits (which is 10000)

So in your case, you now need to specify `?size=25000` in your query (or `"size": 25000` in your JSON query) if you want to get all the possible results back.

Or you can go 10 by 10 (with `size=10`) until you get to `from=24990&size=10`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, @Val! But if I specify `?size=25000` it will pull all the records at one call and it's not what I really want... I still want to pull first 10 records as usual but want to have hits number grater that 10000. Is it possible?

Comment: Actually, just tried to run this query
`POST /articles/_search?size=25000
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query":{"match_all":{}}
}`
and got back this
`{
  "took" : 594,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    ...
  }
}'
Any ideas, why?

Comment: Actually, it works also that way too, you can go 10 by 10 until `from=24990&size=10`

Comment: Right, but it still returns `"hits" : { "total" : { "value" : 10000, "relation" : "gte" } }`, but I would like to get total hits number, not rounded to 10000.

Comment: and I had a feeling that `index.max_result_window` is exactly for that purpose...

Comment: Ok, if you want to get the actual total number of results printed out in the response, you also need to add `?rest_total_hits_as_int=true` to the URL, but that's doesn't prevent you from getting the 25000 hits. That parameter has nothing to do with how many hits you can return, it just gives you an idea of the exact number of hits (if true) and of an approximate number of hits (if false, by default)

Comment: thanks @Val for your help and pointing me to the right direction! Appreciate it! I have found the right answer here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#track-total-hits-10000-default

Comment: @Mr.Pumpkin I'm facing the same issue, can you please let me know what you did to fix this. The above URL you shared returning 404.

Comment: @mohitjain the working link can be found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/breaking-changes-7.0.html#track-total-hits-10000-default